# What does turned through angle or deflected through an angle mean

Tags: classical-mechanics, collision

The question says..  "The direction of motion of A is deflected
through an angle θ by the collision."

What does this mean geometrically?

The whole question [image]

[image]

With theta being the angle being the intial velocity has been turned by is this correct?

Comment: It means that the initial velocity vector of A makes an angle $\theta $ with the final velocity vector of A

Comment: Obviously it must be assumed that A is not spinning for that equation to hold true.

Comment: Yes. v2 has the right meaning of $\theta$.

Comment: Draw the two velocity vectors with their tails together. The angle between the shafts should be $\theta$. Your diagram is not correct.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Deflected Angle D]

Yes, the Deflected Angle $D$ between reflected ray $R$ after collision and incident ray $I$ vectors in as shown.